# How to express "1.275" to "1.28" with Decimal Format in Java

Tags: java, rounding, decimalformat

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat();
decimalFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
decimalFormat.applyPattern(".00");

System.out.print(decimalFormat.format(63.275));
// output : 63.27

System.out.print(decimalFormat.format(64.275));
// output : 64.28
```

Why are they different?

Comment: which ide do you use?

Comment: How do you construct `decimalFormat`?

Comment: Please read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: I use Eclipse Neon

Comment: Java includes 'DecimalFormat' Class. I can use it with 'import'

Comment: I see that you got your answer already.  However, my question was about how you construct `decimalFormat`, _with a lower-case d_, not about how you import the class _with an upper-case D_.  `decimalFormat` is a variable, not a class, and after you import the class, you still need to construct the variable as an instance of the class, using `new` or some method that returns a `DecimalFormat`.  My question was asking how you did that.  Without that info, we don't have full information about your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of 63.275 is recorded in computer as 63.27499999999999857891452847979962825775146484375 . As per the Java API doc "https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_UP " Behaves as for RoundingMode.UP if the discarded fraction is ≥ 0.5; otherwise, behaves as for RoundingMode.DOWN. 
so ,

```
63.27499999999999857891452847979962825775146484375 ~ 63.27
64.275000000000005684341886080801486968994140625 ~ 64.28
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static double roundByPlace(double number, int scale){
    BigDecimal bigDecimal = BigDecimal.valueOf(number);
    String pattern = "0.";
    for(int i = 0; i<scale; i++){
        pattern = pattern+"0";
    }
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
    decimalFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    double result = Double.parseDouble(decimalFormat.format(bigDecimal));
    return result;
}
```